# How to parse the data in Flume

Tags: parsing, apache-kafka, flume

I am trying to parse the data from Flume/Kafka. I have configured Flume.conf file to point to Kafka. I am able to pass a data file from Flume to Kafka. I want to know how I can parse the data to extract few fields from the data file, either in Flume or Kafka. Any advice please? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to persist a subset of fields into Kafka, instead of the complete original data file?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create your own custom Flume Interceptor in order to retain a subset of the fields within the original file. A Flume Interceptor is a piece of code that is run (when configured) immediatelly after the Flume event is created by the source, and before it is put into the channel; i.e. it "intercepts" the event and perform some modifications on it (either in the headers, either in the body) before effectively putting it into the channel.

Once created, it is pretty easy to configure its usage:

```
myagent.sources.mysource.interceptors = myinterceptor
myagent.sources.mysource.interceptors.myintercetor.type = FQCN_of_your_interceptor_class
myagent.sources.mysource.interceptors.myintercetor.specific_parameter_1 = whatever
myagent.sources.mysource.interceptors.myintercetor.specific_parameter_2 = whatever
```

An interceptor class implements the `org.apache.flume.interceptor.Interceptor` [interface](https://flume.apache.org/releases/content/1.6.0/apidocs/org/apache/flume/interceptor/Interceptor.html).